# Issue with recursion approach on two sum problem

Tags: python, recursion

I expect the code to output the indices of number 4 and 2 which is `[0, 2]` because `4 + 2 = 6` the target
But the code return the indicies `[0, 1]`
Here is my approach:

```py
nums = [4, 3, 2]
target = 6
        
total=0     
s=[]
k=[]
def two(i, total):
    if i== 2 or total == target:
        k.append(s.copy())
        return
        
    if i>=2 and total != target:
        return False
    
    s.append(i)
    two(i+1, nums[i]+nums[i+1])

two(0,  0)
print(k)
```

EDIT
Finally I came to this approach and it's work good for three in inputs
Thank's to everyone helped me

```
s=[]


def two_sum(target, nums, i, j):
    if j==len(nums):
        return []
    if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
        s.append(i)
        s.append(j)
        return s
    
    if j>len(nums):
        return False
        
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        return two_sum(target, nums, i, j+1) or two_sum(target, nums, i+j, j+1)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging/logging intermediate values to see what the code does? It does what it's written to do, not what you expect. This is perfectly normal (in the best case, the code matches your expectations, but often enough it doesn't on the first try).

Comment: I think I'm not getting the concept of recursion properly, that's why I code it this way.

Comment: Try printing intermediate results and follow the code to understand. By the way, your `total` global variable is useless as it is shadowed by the argument of same name, so for clarity you should delete it. It also helps if you avoid using globals completely in recursive functions.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I'll try that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is as follows:

```py
def two(nums, target, offset=0):
    if len(nums) < 2:
        return [] # end of recursion condition
    from_deeper = two(nums[1:], target, offset=offset+1) # recursion result from sublist
    return [(offset, offset + i) for i, x in enumerate(nums[1:], start=1) if nums[0] + x == target] + from_deeper

print(two([4, 3, 2], 6)) # [(0, 2)]
print(two([3, 3, 3, 3], 6)) # [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Here I am keeping track of `offset` to correctly adjust the index in the deeper recursion calls.